# change java class in runtime

Tags: java, reflection

I've got a class with number of fields.

```
class MyClass {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

Is it possible to change the name of the field using reflection? (for example to transform `field1` into `field0` and etc.)

Comment: No, it's not possible. But the question should be: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because it operates with precompiled classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the name of the field using reflection?

No.

The closest you can get to this<sup>1</sup> is to change the source code, recompile, and then create a new classloader to load the new class.

But beware that what you will have is a *different* class to the one that you started with:

- Instances of the old class won't acquire the new field.
- Code that was loaded at the same time as the old class will continue to be bound to the old class.

---

<sup>1 - You can achieve the same effect using "byte code engineering", but you still need to load the class again, and the caveats still apply.</sup>

Comment: I see. Well it seems that I have to reimplement class. Because the original problem was that the field in the class which are used in API has bad name and we have no ability to change it. So either we have to reimplement it and then transform one object into another or I thought I could somehow to change field name in runtime.

Comment: Reimplementing is by far the simplest solution.